# Element not visible error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, automation, protractor

I am trying to click on an upload file link on my page however the upload link i said to be not visible.  I've tried hovering over link and the code below.  This has been easily fixed for me before so I'm really confused on how to go about getting this link clicked.
What I've tried:

```js
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var uploadLink = element(by.model('roomPlanCtrl.mm2010File'));

browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(uploadLink), 10000);
uploadLink.click();
```

the HTML:

```html
<span class="dg-link ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ngf-select="" ng-model="roomPlanCtrl.mm2010File" accept=".mms" ng-hide="roomPlanCtrl.hideImportLinks">Upload a MeetingMatrix 2010 File</span>
```

Comment: Are you sure there are no other elements with `ng-show="roomPlanCtrl.showImport2010Ctrls()"`? Have you also tried to maximize the browser window?

Comment: Also can you try to wait until element is visible before clicking on it? probably chaining the wait with click function would help.

Comment: @Alecxe   I uploaded the wrong .html and test code one second while I fix.  really sorry.

Comment: @alecxe the update code, I had that all screwed up sorry.

Comment: @Girish I updated the code I had the wrong html and test code up there

Comment: @alecxe I tried maximize still no luck

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your element is not visible, then you can probably try scrolling to that element and then click on it. If its visible on the page then wait until it loads and then click on it by chaining it to the wait() function. Here's a sample of that -

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var uploadLink = element(by.model('roomPlanCtrl.mm2010File'));
browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(uploadLink), 10000).then(function(){
    uploadLink.click();
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I just tried that, and the hover over text, still says not visible, which is strange because i can click it outside of tests